# Credit Card Type Images with Stripe Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I've been searching through Stripes documentation for a fast solution to the problem of showing credit card logos for currently subscribed users.

<%= current_user.card_type %> shows the credit card name, but I'm unable to add the logo in it's place. Do you have an approach that I can take that won't cause the instance method to fail?

HTML Helper Method that I created with the help of Tyler

```
  def stripe_card_img(card_type)
    case current_user.card_type
      when 'Visa'
        content_tag(:span,'', class: 'fa fa-cc-visa fa-2x', style: 'color: #1a1f71;')
      when 'American Express'
        content_tag(:span, '', class: 'fa-cc-amex fa-2x', style: 'color: #355EB7;')
      when 'Discover'
        content_tag(:span, '', class: 'fa-cc-discover fa-2x', style: 'color: orange')
      when 'JCB'
        content_tag(:span, '', class: 'fa-cc-jcb fa-2x', style: 'green')
      when 'Diners Club'
        content_tag(:span, '', class: 'fa-cc-diners-club fa-2x', style: '#87CEFA')
    end
  end
```

Comment: You could use javascript to load the image in place of the card type.

Comment: Why not just use conditionals around if card_type == 'Visa' ... `<span class='fa fa-cc-visa'></span>`

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. I will try to create a helper method that matches the card logo with the type.

Answer (score 1):

It's verbose, but it works. Using font awesome:

```
<% if current_user.card_type == 'Visa' %><span class="fa fa-cc-visa"></span><% end %>
<% if current_user.card_type == 'American Express' %><span class="fa fa-cc-amex"></span><% end %>
<% if current_user.card_type == 'MasterCard' %><span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></span><% end %>
<% if current_user.card_type == 'Discover' %><span class="fa fa-cc-discover"></span><% end %>
<% if current_user.card_type == 'JCB' %><span class="fa fa-cc-jcb"></span><% end %>
<% if current_user.card_type == 'Diners Club' %><span class="fa fa-cc-diners-club"></span><% end %>
```

case

```
<% case current_user.card_type 
   when 'Visa' %><span class="fa fa-cc-visa"></span>
<% when 'American Express' %><span class="fa fa-cc-amex"></span>
<% when 'MasterCard' %><span class="fa fa-cc-discover"></span>
...
<% end %>
```

helper

```
def stripe_name(card_type)
  [...INSERT CASE/CONDITIONAL...]
end 

<%= stripe_name(current_user.card_type) %>
```

Comment: I tried adding your code to a partial, but it's claiming that there's no view. It works when it's directly added to the form itself, though. I even tried to pass the subscription object to the render argument.